RegexMatchError: get_throttling_function_name: could not find match for multiple v=15.0.0
I cannot use the video download feature via pytube
The code I ran yesterday is not working today. How can I fix the error for pytube 15.0.0?
def video_indir(video_url, dosya_adi):
    video = pytube.YouTube(video_url)
    audio_stream = video.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
    audio_dosya = f'{dosya_adi}.mp4'
    audio_stream.download(filename=audio_dosya)
    return audio_dosya

The error I got is here, the solution is elsewhere."
In Pytube version 15.0.0, you just need to remove ; in line 287 of cipher.py file.
Change r'var {nfunc}\s*=\s*(\[.+?\];)'.format( to r'var {nfunc}\s*=\s*(\[.+?\])'.format( " but I didn't understand it
RegexMatchError: get_throttling_function_name: could not find match for multiple
Traceback:
File "C:\Users\suleymanyasar\Desktop\staj\çalışmalarım\myenv\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 589, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\suleymanyasar\Desktop\staj\çalışmalarım\07-DenemeAI\deneme_app.py", line 76, in <module>
    audio_dosya = video_indir(video_url, dosya_adi)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\suleymanyasar\Desktop\staj\çalışmalarım\07-DenemeAI\deneme_app.py", line 30, in video_indir
    audio_stream = video.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\suleymanyasar\Desktop\staj\çalışmalarım\myenv\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 296, in streams
    return StreamQuery(self.fmt_streams)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\suleymanyasar\Desktop\staj\çalışmalarım\myenv\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 188, in fmt_streams
    extract.apply_signature(stream_manifest, self.vid_info, self.js)
File "C:\Users\suleymanyasar\Desktop\staj\çalışmalarım\myenv\Lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 409, in apply_signature
    cipher = Cipher(js=js)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\suleymanyasar\Desktop\staj\çalışmalarım\myenv\Lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.throttling_plan = get_throttling_plan(js)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\suleymanyasar\Desktop\staj\çalışmalarım\myenv\Lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 405, in get_throttling_plan
    raw_code = get_throttling_function_code(js)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\suleymanyasar\Desktop\staj\çalışmalarım\myenv\Lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 311, in get_throttling_function_code
    name = re.escape(get_throttling_function_name(js))
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\suleymanyasar\Desktop\staj\çalışmalarım\myenv\Lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 296, in get_throttling_function_name
    raise RegexMatchError(


Change the function_patterns array in cipher.py at line 264 to include this one and it seems to work:
function_patterns = [
    # https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/29326#issuecomment-865985377
    # https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/commit/48416bc4a8f1d5ff07d5977659cb8ece7640dcd8
    # var Bpa = [iha];
    # ...
    # a.C && (b = a.get("n")) && (b = Bpa[0](b), a.set("n", b),
    # Bpa.length || iha("")) }};
    # In the above case, `iha` is the relevant function name
    r'a\.[a-zA-Z]\s*&&\s*\([a-z]\s*=\s*a\.get\("n"\)\)\s*&&.*?\|\|\s*([a-z]+)',
    r'\([a-z]\s*=\s*([a-zA-Z0-9$]+)(\[\d+\])?\([a-z]\)',
    r'\([a-z]\s*=\s*([a-zA-Z0-9$]+)(\[\d+\])\([a-z]\)',
]

Reference: https://github.com/amckee/PodTube/blob/master/cipher.patch

this will not work when redeploy to cloud, as we pip install again the wrong code. you will just have to wait for the fix PR to be merge or use other lib, for none local use.

I agree with what you said, I use another library. I learned that there are constant problems with pytube. It may be better than other libraries in terms of performance, but these errors push the user to other options.
import yt_dlp

its an issue i have faced recently with pytube you can just use the pytubefix fork on github from the pytubefix
pip install pytubefix

